# How to evaluate if an extracted link is a subpath

Tags: python, path, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl some pages. I am using python 2.7. 
The spider returns the response object, and I am inspecting URLs found on the page. I want to restrict the spider to only follow URLS that are subpaths of a location I specify.

For instance, I would like to specify that the spider should only follows links below www.google.com/policies/privacy/

The links extracted from the response object follow a number of different conventions.

E.g.

- ../../policies/privacy/
- ../../policies/privacy/example/collect-information.html
- #infocollect
- /intl/en_uk/policies/privacy/google_privacy_policy_en_uk.pdf
- //myaccount.google.com/
- https://support.google.com/policies/troubleshooter/2990837?hl=en-GB

I can't work out how to do it. I have just used a simple find method on the string. It's not robust or that clever it seems to me.

```
import scrapy

class googleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "google"
    allowed_domains = ["google.co.uk"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/policies/privacy/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
            if href.find('/policies/privacy/') != -1:
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: Can you share the Scrapy code you tried so far?

Comment: Sure. You can see I'm not tackling the issue properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`LinkExtractor`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html?#module-scrapy.linkextractors) for this. The default one normalizes the links.

Then, it's a matter of building `Requests` out of the links you get from `.extract_links(response)`

Check this `scrapy shell` example:

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/
2016-06-22 18:03:19 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...edited...)
2016-06-22 18:03:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/> (referer: None)
(...edited...)

>>> from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
>>> for l in LinkExtractor().extract_links(response):
...     print(l.url)
... 
https://www.google.com/
(...edited...)
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046?hl=en
https://www.google.com/trends/
https://www.youtube.com/trendsmap
https://privacy.google.com/?hl=en
https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/location-data/
https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/wallet/
https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/voice/
https://www.google.com/safetycenter/families/start/
https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/
https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/
https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/

>>> for l in LinkExtractor().extract_links(response):
...     if response.url in l.url:
...         print(l.url)
... 
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/frameworks/
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/key-terms/
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/partners/
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/archive/
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/more-relevant-search-results.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/connect-with-people.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/sharing-with-others.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/ads-youll-find-most-useful.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/the-people-who-matter-most.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/credit-card.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/collect-information.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/view-and-interact-with-our-ads.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/device-specific-information.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/device-identifiers.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/phone-number.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/may-collect-and-process-information.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/sensors.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/wifi-access-points-and-cell-towers.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/our-partners.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/advertising-services.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/linked-with-information-about-visits-to-multiple-sites.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/provide-services.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/maintain-services.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/protect-services.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/develop-new-ones.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/protect-google-and-our-users.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/limit-sharing-or-visibility-settings.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/improve-your-user-experience.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/combine-personal-information.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/to-make-it-easier-to-share.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/may-not-function-properly.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/sharing.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/removing-your-content.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/access-to-your-personal-information.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/legal-process.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/we-may-share.html
https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/example/to-show-trends.html
```

Comment: Hey paul, thanks a lot. That really solved my problem. I knew there must be an inbuilt method to deal with links. Thanks a lot.